# Placing a banner at the top of the screen within safe area? (rather than bottom)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code from IronSource to place a banner, however it is showing at the bottom, not the top.

What I want to do is get the banner to show at the TOP rather than the bottom , the code below works fine, but obviously shows at the bottom not the top.

I tried changing the

```
y -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
```

to

```
y -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.top;
```

But it didn't work.

This is the full code for showing the banner;

```
#pragma mark - Orientation delegate
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.bannerView) {
            CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - (self.bannerView.frame.size.height / 2);
            if (@available(ios 11.0, *)) {
                y -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
            }
            self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y);
        }
    });
}
 
#pragma mark - Banner Delegate Functions
- (void)bannerDidLoad:(ISBannerView *)bannerView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.bannerView = bannerView;
       
        CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - (self.bannerView.frame.size.height / 2);
        if (@available(ios 11.0, *)) {
            y -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
        }
        self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y);
       
        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want the Top of the banner to be at the Top of the **View** (so it overlays the safe area)? Or, do you want it to be below the Top fo the safe area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be using auto-layout / constraints - then you wouldn't need any of that.

But, assuming you have a valid reason ***NOT*** to, try it like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.bannerView) {
        CGFloat y = 0;
        if (@available(ios 11.0, *)) {
            y = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top;
        }
        self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y + self.bannerView.frame.size.height / 2);
    }
});
```

If you want to make your life easier, change your `bannerDidLoad` method to this:

```
- (void)bannerDidLoad:(ISBannerView *)bannerView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.bannerView = bannerView;

        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];

        self.bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        [self.bannerView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.bannerView.frame.size.width].active = YES;
        [self.bannerView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:self.bannerView.frame.size.height].active = YES;
        [self.bannerView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
        if (@available(ios 11.0, *)) {
            [self.bannerView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
        } else {
            [self.bannerView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
        }
    });
}
```

and you can eliminate your `- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification` method altogether.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you DonMag - the aim was purely to get the banner at the top rather than the bottom - and this has explained it perfectly - answer marked as correct, thank you!

Comment: @user1695971 - glad it worked for you. Be sure to mark the answer as "Accepted" as well.